# steep check returns RBS::UnknownTypeName on DateTime

Tags: ruby, rbs, steep

I am implementing a .rbs file for the ruby code and everything works but the `DateTime`. This is what I have:

ruby file:

```rb
class foo
  # other attributes
  attr_reader :bar

  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end

end
```

this is the rbs file:

```
class Foo
  # other attributes
  attr_reader bar: DateTime

  def initialize: (DateTime bar) -> void

end
```

but when I run `steep check` I get the following error:

```
path/foo.rbs:14:26: [error] Cannot find type `DateTime`
│ Diagnostic ID: RBS::UnknownTypeName
│
└   attr_reader bar: DateTime
```

Why is DateTime not being found? should it be a different declaration?

the rest of the types works fine, either if they are created by me or if they are basic ones like `Integer` or `String`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly add the date standard library types to your `Steepfile`

```rb
target :lib do
  signature "sig"
  
  check "lib"

  library "date" # add standard libraries here
end
```

I didn't find any good documentation for this, the I pieced it together by reading [steep's `Steepfile`](https://github.com/soutaro/steep/blob/master/Steepfile).
This is how I guess it works:

- Types that are automatically loaded by ruby are available by rbs/steep out of the box. Those signatures are in [rbs/core](https://github.com/ruby/rbs/tree/master/core)).
- The standard library that is not loaded automatically, e.g.
  `DateTime`, is not available by rbs/steep unless you explicitly declare them in the `Steepfile` as `library`. Those signatures are in [rbs/stdlib](https://github.com/ruby/rbs/tree/master/stdlib).